# How to get raw android camera sensor image data using JNI+OpenCV+NDK?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am using camera2 api for my app which is based on [Camera2Raw](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Raw).

```
mRawImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largestRaw.getWidth(), 
       largestRaw.getHeight(),ImageFormat.RAW_SENSOR, /*maxImages*/
```

I have `image` from `ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener`, Instead of saving DNG file,  I am passing its byte array to my native opencv function to process:

```
int w = image.getWidth();
int h = image.getHeight();
ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
byte[] data = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
buffer.get(data);
addShot(w, h, data);
image.close();
```

and C++ function:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL addShot(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jint width, jint height, jbyteArray p_data)
   {
       jbyte* _p_data= env->GetByteArrayElements(p_data, 0);
       Mat srcBGR(height, width, CV_8UC3);
       Mat mdata(height, width, CV_8UC3, (unsigned char *)_p_data);
//        Mat tmp_mat= imdecode(mdata,1);
       cvtColor(mdata, srcBGR, CV_RGB2BGR);
       env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(p_data, _p_data, 0);
   }
```

First. for making sure, I am trying to save as JPEG in c++ side. But The result has many green colors.

I think there is missing part in my c++ code.

Can anyone help for this?

Comment: [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#RAW_SENSOR): "General raw camera sensor image format, usually representing a single-channel Bayer-mosaic image. Each pixel color sample is stored with 16 bits of precision." -- Is that not so in your case? Because you seem to be treating it as a 3 channel RGB image with 8 bit precision. That seems rather odd.

Comment: Yes right. I think my c++ code maybe for another case like YUV format. The code I posted was my trial, Image processing is not my area :( so I am asking help. I would appreciate a lot if someone guide me

Comment: android-24 added NdkCamera, you might be able to get the camera image directly from there.  The header files are under NDK's platforms include/camera, include/media ( for AImagerReader ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing Bayer RAW data is not trivial - it's raw readout of pixel values off the sensor, and you need a lot of extra metadata and processing to convert it to a viewable image.  If you don't know how to do that, I don't recommend trying - you can just plug in a library like [Adobe's DNG SDK](https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/dng/dng_sdk.html), or [libraw](http://www.libraw.org/).

Are you sure you don't just want YUV_420_888 data, which is processed but uncompressed?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The libraries you sent are for PC? I am trying to process just in the mobile app.  I used to use `YUV_420_888` data. When I save DNG file and using [RawDroid Demo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anthonymandra.rawdroid&hl=en) converted to JPEG. The result was awesome. So I am trying to do something rawdroid does

Comment: Also using YUV_420_888, didn't work in Google Pixel XL

Comment: YUV_420_888 should work fine on Pixel XL - are you using a size that's actually listed for YUV_420_888, or did you try to reuse the RAW size? They don't have the exact same sizes, since processing to YUV typically makes the image a bit smaller (to match common aspect ratios, etc).

The Adobe DNG SDK works on Android these days, as far as I know (it's even in the Android AOSP source tree in Android Nougat).  Don't know if libraw does. If you want to write your own RAW processing pipeline, there's a ton to learn there, and it's kind of out of scope of a simple StackOverflow answer.

Comment: See Wikipedia's article on RAW for what all needs to be done to make a JPEG out of a RAW file: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format

Comment: I ended up with the solutuon using samsung camera sdk http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/camera

Answer (score 1):

After capturing RAW image data, using simple OpenCV function reads from the buffer memory.

```
Mat mImageMat;
mImageMat = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(data), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

where, `mImageMat` is Mat class of Image Container.

Then, processing the image becomes simple.

Comment: Oh thank you! How can I make this work in JNI? I am using opencv in native cpp part, not in java

Comment: Mat class can be passed to JNI using `.getNativeObjAddr()`